# getJsonConfig not working on second call

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute

In my wishlist I'm calling getJsonConfig on each product. The `['attributes']` is the only information that I'm using. For the first/top product in the wishlist there is no problem. But the second product returns everything except the `['attributes']` index is empty.

If I remove the first/top product and force the second to become the new first/top product `['attributes']` is populated.

An example of what the first/top product returns is as follows

```
object(stdClass)#881 (7) {
["attributes"] => object(stdClass)#889 (1) {
["155"] => object(stdClass)#890 (4) {
  ["id"] => string(3) "155"
  ["code"] => string(4) "size"
  ["label"] => string(4) "Size"
  ["options"] => array(4) {
    [0] => object(stdClass)#882 (5) {
      ["id"] => string(2) "29"
      ["label"] => string(2) "XS"
      ["price"] => string(1) "0"
      ["oldPrice"] => string(1) "0"
      ["products"] => array(1) {
        [0] => string(3) "714"
      }
    }
    [1] => object(stdClass)#883 (5) {
      ["id"] => string(1) "4"
      ["label"] => string(1) "M"
      ["price"] => string(1) "0"
      ["oldPrice"] => string(1) "0"
      ["products"] => array(1) {
        [0] => string(3) "716"
      }
    }
    [2] => object(stdClass)#884 (5) {
      ["id"] => string(1) "3"
      ["label"] => string(1) "L"
      ["price"] => string(1) "0"
      ["oldPrice"] => string(1) "0"
      ["products"] => array(1) {
        [0] => string(3) "717"
      }
    }
    [3] => object(stdClass)#885 (5) {
      ["id"] => string(1) "5"
      ["label"] => string(1) "S"
      ["price"] => string(1) "0"
      ["oldPrice"] => string(1) "0"
      ["products"] => array(1) {
        [0] => string(3) "718"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
["template"] => string(9) "$#{price}"
["basePrice"] => string(3) "858"
["oldPrice"] => string(3) "858"
["productId"] => string(3) "715"
["chooseText"] => string(19) "Choose an Option..."
["taxConfig"] => object(stdClass)#886 (6) {
["includeTax"] => bool(false)
["showIncludeTax"] => bool(false)
["showBothPrices"] => bool(false)
["defaultTax"] => int(0)
["currentTax"] => int(0)
["inclTaxTitle"] => string(9) "Incl. Tax"
}
}
```

And the second looks like

```
object(stdClass)#964 (7) {
["attributes"] => array(0) {
}
["template"] => string(9) "$#{price}"
["basePrice"] => string(6) "127.57"
["oldPrice"] => string(6) "127.57"
["productId"] => string(3) "659"
["chooseText"] => string(19) "Choose an Option..."
["taxConfig"] => object(stdClass)#778 (6) {
["includeTax"] => bool(false)
["showIncludeTax"] => bool(false)
["showBothPrices"] => bool(false)
["defaultTax"] => int(0)
["currentTax"] => int(0)
["inclTaxTitle"] => string(9) "Incl. Tax"
}
}
```

I call this from the template like this

```
<?php
if($_product && $_product->isConfigurable()){
    $checkoutLinksBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_view_type_configurable')->setTemplate('wishlist/item/column/configurable.phtml')->setProduct($_product);
    echo '<div style="display:none;" class="config-options" id="'. $_product->getId() .'">' . $checkoutLinksBlock->renderView() . '</div>';

}

$checkoutLinksBlock->renderView() just contains a zend_debug::dump($this->getJsonConfig());
```

getJsonConfig() refers to this function in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php

```
public function getJsonConfig()
{
    $attributes = array();
    $options    = array();
    $store      = $this->getCurrentStore();
    $taxHelper  = Mage::helper('tax');
    $currentProduct = $this->getProduct();

    $preconfiguredFlag = $currentProduct->hasPreconfiguredValues();
    if ($preconfiguredFlag) {
        $preconfiguredValues = $currentProduct->getPreconfiguredValues();
        $defaultValues       = array();
    }

    foreach ($this->getAllowProducts() as $product) {
        $productId  = $product->getId();

        foreach ($this->getAllowAttributes() as $attribute) {
            $productAttribute   = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
            $productAttributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
            $attributeValue     = $product->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());
            if (!isset($options[$productAttributeId])) {
                $options[$productAttributeId] = array();
            }

            if (!isset($options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue])) {
                $options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue] = array();
            }
            $options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue][] = $productId;
        }
    }

    $this->_resPrices = array(
        $this->_preparePrice($currentProduct->getFinalPrice())
    );

    foreach ($this->getAllowAttributes() as $attribute) {
        $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
        $attributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
        $info = array(
           'id'        => $productAttribute->getId(),
           'code'      => $productAttribute->getAttributeCode(),
           'label'     => $attribute->getLabel(),
           'options'   => array()
        );

        $optionPrices = array();
        $prices = $attribute->getPrices();
        if (is_array($prices)) {
            foreach ($prices as $value) {
                if(!$this->_validateAttributeValue($attributeId, $value, $options)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $currentProduct->setConfigurablePrice(
                    $this->_preparePrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent'])
                );
                $currentProduct->setParentId(true);
                Mage::dispatchEvent(
                    'catalog_product_type_configurable_price',
                    array('product' => $currentProduct)
                );
                $configurablePrice = $currentProduct->getConfigurablePrice();

                if (isset($options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']])) {
                    $productsIndex = $options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']];
                } else {
                    $productsIndex = array();
                }

                $info['options'][] = array(
                    'id'        => $value['value_index'],
                    'label'     => $value['label'],
                    'price'     => $configurablePrice,
                    'oldPrice'  => $this->_prepareOldPrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
                    'products'  => $productsIndex,
                );
                $optionPrices[] = $configurablePrice;
            }
        }
        /**
         * Prepare formated values for options choose
         */
        foreach ($optionPrices as $optionPrice) {
            foreach ($optionPrices as $additional) {
                $this->_preparePrice(abs($additional-$optionPrice));
            }
        }
        if($this->_validateAttributeInfo($info)) {
           $attributes[$attributeId] = $info;
        }

        // Add attribute default value (if set)
        if ($preconfiguredFlag) {
            $configValue = $preconfiguredValues->getData('super_attribute/' . $attributeId);
            if ($configValue) {
                $defaultValues[$attributeId] = $configValue;
            }
        }
    }

    $taxCalculation = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation');
    if (!$taxCalculation->getCustomer() && Mage::registry('current_customer')) {
        $taxCalculation->setCustomer(Mage::registry('current_customer'));
    }

    $_request = $taxCalculation->getDefaultRateRequest();
    $_request->setProductClassId($currentProduct->getTaxClassId());
    $defaultTax = $taxCalculation->getRate($_request);

    $_request = $taxCalculation->getRateRequest();
    $_request->setProductClassId($currentProduct->getTaxClassId());
    $currentTax = $taxCalculation->getRate($_request);

    $taxConfig = array(
        'includeTax'        => $taxHelper->priceIncludesTax(),
        'showIncludeTax'    => $taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax(),
        'showBothPrices'    => $taxHelper->displayBothPrices(),
        'defaultTax'        => $defaultTax,
        'currentTax'        => $currentTax,
        'inclTaxTitle'      => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Incl. Tax')
    );

    $config = array(
        'attributes'        => $attributes,
        'template'          => str_replace('%s', '#{price}', $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getOutputFormat()),
        'basePrice'         => $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($currentProduct->getFinalPrice())),
        'oldPrice'          => $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($currentProduct->getPrice())),
        'productId'         => $currentProduct->getId(),
        'chooseText'        => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Choose an Option...'),
        'taxConfig'         => $taxConfig
    );

    if ($preconfiguredFlag && !empty($defaultValues)) {
        $config['defaultValues'] = $defaultValues;
    }

    $config = array_merge($config, $this->_getAdditionalConfig());

    return Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($config);
}
```

As you can see the product Id section is different on each and I've checked that it is the product I think it is. The second object will populate the `["attributes"]` if I remove the first product from the wishlist.

So why is there an issue getting this configuration data for multiple products on a single page.

P.S. I've tried this with lots of products so it's not a once off issue. It is consistent whatever products are in the wishlist.

Comment: Could you please add to the description the code of `getJsonConfig()` method.

Comment: I've added the function code and location

Comment: If you will will follow `$this->getProduct()` method code you will find out that it will always return you the same instance of the product. How do you display this block programmatically?

Comment: it's returning a different product per call. I'm setting the product `$checkoutLinksBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_view_type_configurable')->setTemplate('wishlist/item/column/configurable.phtml')->setProduct($_product);` and i've tested this by outputting the product id within `getJsonConfig`

Comment: Try to use `createBlock` instead of `getBlockSingleton`.

Comment: that did it. I forgot the singleton version is the same instance. If you like you can write the answer and I'll accept it. I'll add it if not. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the problem is that you use getBlockSingleton, which probabably cache the information about the first product. Try to use createBlock() method. This will create new instance of the block and should solve your problem.